# Microsoft.Activities not found

Tags: nuget

I am using Visual Studio 2012 premium and have NuGet package installed. From the Package manager console, I issued the Install-Package command to get Microsoft.Activities but I got the following error:

```
PM> Install-Package "Microsoft.Activities"
Install-Package : Unable to find package 'Microsoft.Activities'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package "Microsoft.Activities"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

Could it be something I did incorrectly, typo or something simple? I tried to `Get-Package -ListAvailable` and see the Microsoft.Activities there...just can not install it to my project.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Microsoft.ACtivities has been unlisted.
http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Activities
you might want to contact the owner to see what are the alternatives:  http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Activities/ContactOwners

from http://wf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Microsoft.Activities%20Overview it looks like it might have changed to microsoft.activities.extensions as bhuvak suggested above.

Answer (score 1):

The command looks fine. Are you trying to install from Nuget Official Source ( http://nuget.org) ? There is no package  by Id Microsoft.Activities.  There are packages with ids Microsoft.Activities.UnitTesting and Microsoft.Activities.Extensions..